# Why is this bootstrap navigation not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I am using the exact code suggested by Bootstrap:-

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse5" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbarCollapse5" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rLmwu4qc/).

Please note that I did use Bootstrap CSS and JS as external resources in my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rLmwu4qc/).

Comment: what's not working?

Comment: @sumitchauhan Please run the JSFiddle and see the result, the navigation is not displaying as it is supposed to.

Comment: did your read the bootstrap documentation ?

Comment: Yes, I did and then I came across a tutorial on creating responsive navigation using Bootstrap here - https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-navbar.php
But when I create the JSfiddle using the exact code, it won't work.

Comment: @lk_wp you are using bootstrap 4 not 3

Comment: so you need the markup for v4

Comment: see your markup with v3 https://jsfiddle.net/rLmwu4qc/1/, it works

Answer (score 1):

Try now it is working for me your are using Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta.2 try to use 3.3.7

```css
    .bs-example{
     margin: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Static Navbar</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head> 
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: he is using bootstrap 4 not 3

Answer (score 1):

You need to ether use the [v4 markup](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/) for your current version of bootstrap or to use [v3 for your current markup](https://jsfiddle.net/rLmwu4qc/1/)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```