# Bootstrap navigation is not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

Bootstrap is not working when i am trying to give class navbar navbar-inverse it dosen't work here i am going to provide code.
and my cosole error is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined at setTransitionEndSupport.

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#/home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/add">Add</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/edit">Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/delete">Delete</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <script src="scripts/angular-min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="demo.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you provide code snippet?

Comment: Check it @Rupal

Comment: bootstrap which version are you using?

Comment: check you console for any errors..

Comment: bootstrap version 4.0

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined at setTransitionEndSupport. This is my console error

Comment: i think no class called navbar-inverse in bootstrap 4. plz check documentation

Comment: <div role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse"> replace this by <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse"> and  for reference follow https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp

Comment: go through the docs if you are using Bootstrap V4... https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#nav

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is this bootstrap navigation not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068048/why-is-this-bootstrap-navigation-not-working)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said you are using bootstrap 4 and you using navbar of bootstrap 3 so it not working. I have added nav code of bootstrap 4 and its working. Check below snippet

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
   <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
 
    
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-light">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Active</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
   
  </ul>
</nav>
   
    <div ng-view></div>
    <script src="scripts/angular-min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="demo.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

or check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_navs.asp)